# java.sql.Types.JSON is not a default JDBC type

Tags: java, mysql, json, oracle, postgresql

JSON is a common database type for all of major SQL databases.
I'm not understand why there isn't a java.sql.Types.JSON as a default JDBC type.

Answer (score 0):

The class  *java.sql.Types* defines the constants that are used to identify generic SQL types. JSON is not a generic SQL type. JSON is rather a standard data interchange format.

Comment: This isn't hugely helpful as MySQL has supported a JSON column type since version 5.7.8 was released in August 2015, including functionality such as validation on INSERT, JSON normalization, and the column path and inline path operators "-> and -->" to interrogate the JSON directly from a SQL query, etc. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) So to say that java.sql.Types only defines "*generic* SQL types" is almost meaningless. Indeed the phrase "generic SQL type" seems to be used almost exclusively by the JDBC documentation...

Comment: @RichPollock: SQL:2016 did introduce JSON support to the SQL standard. However the standard did not introduce a new _data type_ to store that. It assumes JSON values are stored in a `CLOB` or `VARCHAR` column. The JDBC interface tries to go "along with the SQL standard" and as there is no specific type for JSON in the standard, there is no need in JDBC to define one (btw: Postgres has supported JSON much longer than MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context where you need the equivalent type, `com.mysql.cj.MysqlType.FIELD_TYPE_JSON` or `java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR` should work.